# JSON.parse() crashes on chrome

Tags: json, google-chrome, crash

Chome (80.0.3987.132 windows build) crashes on parsing Json.

For reproduce :

1- Open this [link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fauguste/ddcad71050a87ea80b301640aad494a7/raw/b150b5aec2258d4be0cc0a9660347505071d97b7/parese_error.json).

2- Type these lines on Console :

```
var json = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText;
JSON.parse(json);
```

The json file is valid.

Can someone help us to solve this crash ?

Thanks,

Comment: This was a bug in (the JavaScript Engine of) Chrome 80 and [should be fixed](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/v8/v8/+/1970211) in Chrome 81.

Comment: I can confirm that it works with Google Chrome Canary (v82) but it doesn't work with Google Chrome (v80). The order of the keys seem to crash the browser

Comment: Chrome 81 has been released and this is indeed fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is problem with 1st unit key in Chrome (but not in FF):

```js
function test() {
  var x = document.body.innerText;
  var code = x.indexOf("function");
  if(code > -1) x = x.substr(0, code);
  var y = JSON.parse(x)
  console.log(y);
}
```

```html
<body onload=test() style="display:none">{"rooms": [{"tasks": [{"id": 5438567,"price": 0.0,"name": "XXXXXX","unit": "unité","timePerUnit": 0,"consumablePrice": 0.0,"vat": 0.0,"sellProductVat": 0.0,"imageUrl": null,"description": "XXXXXX","surfaceType": null,"referentialId": null,"quantity": 1.0,"detailedPrice": {"id": 7928388,"totalPrice": 5413.1,"totalPriceExcludingTaxes": 0.0,"totalPriceExcludingProducts": 0.0,"consumablesPrice": 0.0,"disasterFundPrice": 0.0,"artisanWorkforcePrice": 0.0,"homegeniusPrice": 0.0,"managerBasePrice": 0.0,"managerWorkforcePrice": 0.0,"leroyMerlinProductsPrice": 0.0,"otherProductsPrice": 0.0},"type": "custom-customer","tasks": [{"id": 5438568,"price": 3700.0,"name": "XXXXXX","unit": "unité","timePerUnit": 0,"consumablePrice": 0.0,"vat": 0.1,"sellProductVat": 0.0,"imageUrl": null,"description": "XXXXXX","surfaceType": null,"referentialId": null,"quantity": 1.0,"type": "custom-customer","tasks": [],"products": [],"creationDate": "2020-03-02T14:34:42.000+0000","version": 12,"payee": "artisan","isSelected": true,"legacyRenovationId": "","previousRenovationId": "","isWorkforceActivated": true,"isProductsActivated": true,"renovationId": "","detailedPrice": 11}],"products": [],"creationDate": "2020-03-02T14:34:42.000+0000","version": 12,"payee": "artisan","isSelected": false,"legacyRenovationId": "","previousRenovationId": "","isWorkforceActivated": true,"isProductsActivated": true,"renovationId": ""},{"id": 5438563,"price": null,"name": "XXXXXXXXXXXX","unit": null,"timePerUnit": null,"consumablePrice": null,"vat": null,"sellProductVat": null,"imageUrl": "","description": "","surfaceType": "floor","referentialId": 30,"quantity": 1.0,"detailedPrice": {"id": 7928386,"totalPrice": 1602.07,"totalPriceExcludingTaxes": 0.0,"totalPriceExcludingProducts": 0.0,"consumablesPrice": 0.0,"disasterFundPrice": 0.0,"artisanWorkforcePrice": 0.0,"homegeniusPrice": 0.0,"managerBasePrice": 0.0,"managerWorkforcePrice": 0.0,"leroyMerlinProductsPrice": 0.0,"otherProductsPrice": 0.0},"type": "referential","tasks": [{"id": 5438566,"price": 50.0,"name": "XXXXXXXXXX","unit": "m²","timePerUnit": 18,"consumablePrice": 10.0,"vat": 0.1,"sellProductVat": 0.1,"imageUrl": null,"description": "","surfaceType": "floor","referentialId": 33,"quantity": 12.0,"detailedPrice": {"id": 7928385,"totalPrice": 494.52,"totalPriceExcludingTaxes": 0.0,"totalPriceExcludingProducts": 0.0,"consumablesPrice": 0.0,"disasterFundPrice": 0.0,"artisanWorkforcePrice": 0.0,"homegeniusPrice": 0.0,"managerBasePrice": 0.0,"managerWorkforcePrice": 0.0,"leroyMerlinProductsPrice": 0.0,"otherProductsPrice": 0.0},"type": "referential","tasks": [],"products": [],"creationDate": "2020-03-02T14:33:33.000+0000","version": 12,"payee": "artisan","isSelected": true,"legacyRenovationId": "fac1ec489e","previousRenovationId": "5438205","isWorkforceActivated": true,"isProductsActivated": true,"renovationId": "5438566"}],"products": [],"creationDate": "2020-03-02T14:33:33.000+0000","version": 12,"payee": "artisan","isSelected": false,"legacyRenovationId": "8892e346b0","previousRenovationId": "5438202","isWorkforceActivated": true,"isProductsActivated": true,"renovationId": "5438563"}]}]}</body>
```

But this without first unit not ;-)

```js
function test() {
  var x = document.body.innerText;
  x = x.substr(0,x.indexOf("function")).replace("unit", "here");
  var y = JSON.parse(x);
  alert(JSON.stringify(y,null,2));
}
```

```html
<body onload=test() style="display:none">{
  "rooms": [
    {
      "tasks": [
        {
          "id": 5438567,
          "price": 0.0,
          "name": "XXXXXX",
          "unit": "unité","timePerUnit": 0,"consumablePrice": 0.0,"vat": 0.0,"sellProductVat": 0.0,"imageUrl": null,"description": "XXXXXX","surfaceType": null,"referentialId": null,"quantity": 1.0,"detailedPrice": {"id": 7928388,"totalPrice": 5413.1,"totalPriceExcludingTaxes": 0.0,"totalPriceExcludingProducts": 0.0,"consumablesPrice": 0.0,"disasterFundPrice": 0.0,"artisanWorkforcePrice": 0.0,"homegeniusPrice": 0.0,"managerBasePrice": 0.0,"managerWorkforcePrice": 0.0,"leroyMerlinProductsPrice": 0.0,"otherProductsPrice": 0.0},"type": "custom-customer","tasks": [{"id": 5438568,"price": 3700.0,"name": "XXXXXX","unit": "unité","timePerUnit": 0,"consumablePrice": 0.0,"vat": 0.1,"sellProductVat": 0.0,"imageUrl": null,"description": "XXXXXX","surfaceType": null,"referentialId": null,"quantity": 1.0,"type": "custom-customer","tasks": [],"products": [],"creationDate": "2020-03-02T14:34:42.000+0000","version": 12,"payee": "artisan","isSelected": true,"legacyRenovationId": "","previousRenovationId": "","isWorkforceActivated": true,"isProductsActivated": true,"renovationId": "","detailedPrice": 11}],"products": [],"creationDate": "2020-03-02T14:34:42.000+0000","version": 12,"payee": "artisan","isSelected": false,"legacyRenovationId": "","previousRenovationId": "","isWorkforceActivated": true,"isProductsActivated": true,"renovationId": ""},{"id": 5438563,"price": null,"name": "XXXXXXXXXXXX","unit": null,"timePerUnit": null,"consumablePrice": null,"vat": null,"sellProductVat": null,"imageUrl": "","description": "","surfaceType": "floor","referentialId": 30,"quantity": 1.0,"detailedPrice": {"id": 7928386,"totalPrice": 1602.07,"totalPriceExcludingTaxes": 0.0,"totalPriceExcludingProducts": 0.0,"consumablesPrice": 0.0,"disasterFundPrice": 0.0,"artisanWorkforcePrice": 0.0,"homegeniusPrice": 0.0,"managerBasePrice": 0.0,"managerWorkforcePrice": 0.0,"leroyMerlinProductsPrice": 0.0,"otherProductsPrice": 0.0},"type": "referential","tasks": [{"id": 5438566,"price": 50.0,"name": "XXXXXXXXXX","unit": "m²","timePerUnit": 18,"consumablePrice": 10.0,"vat": 0.1,"sellProductVat": 0.1,"imageUrl": null,"description": "","surfaceType": "floor","referentialId": 33,"quantity": 12.0,"detailedPrice": {"id": 7928385,"totalPrice": 494.52,"totalPriceExcludingTaxes": 0.0,"totalPriceExcludingProducts": 0.0,"consumablesPrice": 0.0,"disasterFundPrice": 0.0,"artisanWorkforcePrice": 0.0,"homegeniusPrice": 0.0,"managerBasePrice": 0.0,"managerWorkforcePrice": 0.0,"leroyMerlinProductsPrice": 0.0,"otherProductsPrice": 0.0},"type": "referential","tasks": [],"products": [],"creationDate": "2020-03-02T14:33:33.000+0000","version": 12,"payee": "artisan","isSelected": true,"legacyRenovationId": "fac1ec489e","previousRenovationId": "5438205","isWorkforceActivated": true,"isProductsActivated": true,"renovationId": "5438566"}],"products": [],"creationDate": "2020-03-02T14:33:33.000+0000","version": 12,"payee": "artisan","isSelected": false,"legacyRenovationId": "8892e346b0","previousRenovationId": "5438202","isWorkforceActivated": true,"isProductsActivated": true,"renovationId": "5438563"}]}]}
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's strange, I thinks its a chrome issue. Chromium working fine.

Comment: The issue isn't necessarily `unit`. You can basically remove any property and it will work fine again. If you remove every `unit` from the JSON it will be broken again. Seems this issue is caused by very specific nesting of (structure wise) identical objects. I'd say this is a bug in Chrome. Might be worth filing a bug report.

Comment: I filed a bug report which can be seen [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1059208). I've also been able to shrink the JSON down a fair amount which can also be found in that report.